# Why does my visualisation disappear after clicking a button using ControlP5 in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

I am working on a application using Processing. I'd like to create two buttons using Control P5. After I press on of the keys, I want to show some content. However, it immediately disappears and I am not sure why.

#### setup()

```
import controlP5.*;

ControlP5 cp5;
controlP5.Button b;

void setup() {
    size(1080,720);
    background(210,210,210);
    cp5 = new ControlP5(this);

    b = cp5.addButton("A")
        .setPosition(100,140)
        .setSize(200,19);


    b = cp5.addButton("B")
       .setPosition(100,180)
       .setSize(200,19);
}
```

#### draw()

```
void draw() {
    background(0);
}
```

#### button functions()

```
public void A() {
    println("This is a");
    text("word", 100, 100);
}

public void B() {
    println("This is b");    
}
```

I'd like to know, how I would accomplish a situation - where I can click on button A, a visualisation shows up. And when I click on button B, a new visualisation shows up and hides the one from button A.

Because now, when I click on button A, 'word' shows for a second and disappears right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `A()` is only called once whenever a button is pressed, unlike `draw()` which is called repeatedly and so you see only like a single frame of the `text()`. There is a way to fix this, basically you want to draw everything in `draw()` just choose what to draw and when to draw. You could do this using a boolean flag:

```
boolean drawText = false;

void draw() {
  background(0);
  if (drawText)
    text("word", 100, 100);
}

public void A() {
  drawText = true;
  println("This is a"); 
}

public void B() {
  drawText = false;
  println("This is b");
}
```

Comment: This answered my question nicely. Thanks!

Comment: I've got one more tiny question, what if I don't want to show anything yet at the start of the program? Only when the user clicks either A or B, something happens on the screen?

Comment: @JoshWilliams That is what happens currently, right? There is nothing on the screen but the two buttons, when you press A, text appears, when you press B, text disappears

Comment: I've found the bug. I know what you mean. You're right! Thanks again :)

Comment: @JoshWilliams No problem!

Comment: I have a small question about your post. I added some dynamic visualisations instead of 'text()', but since the draw()-method is a loop, my visualisation keeps reloading/redrawing everytime. Is there any way to just click the button and show the visualisation once using this code?

Comment: @JoshWilliams You should ask another question in a separate post so that people(including me) will be able to help you better, moreover, it will be more useful for other visitors of this site looking for help.